# Finding already existing value in Key Value pair

Tags: c#, .net, key-value

I am storing a string and int value in Key value pair.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

While adding i need to check if string(Key) already exists in list, if exists i need to add it to Value instead of adding new key.
How to check and add?

Comment: So why dont you use a `Dictionary` then?

Comment: Note that `KeyValuePair<string, int>` is immutable.  You would have to remove the existing entry and create a new one every time you wanted to update the value.  Which is why a `Dictionary` is much better as given in the answers.

Comment: Thanks, i am going with Dictionary.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of List you can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and check if it [contains key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) then add the new value to the existing key

```
int newValue = 10;
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("key"))
    dictionary["key"] = dictionary["key"] + newValue;
```

Comment: Just a note: Dictionary doesn't allow accessing by index. If that's a requirement (as it is in my case), then this is not a viable solution.

Comment: @Dan, `Dictionary` does allow access by index, like `dictionary["myKey"]` I am not sure what you meant.

Comment: But on the other hand Dictionary doesn't support same keys with different values.

Comment: @Dan, You can use ElementAt[myInt] if you need to get entries by position.

Comment: @BH Thanks, I'll try that next time I need it.

Comment: The OP asks for a List why suggest him a Dictionary? Dictionarys cant be sorted and lots of other differences.

Answer (score 8):

use dictonary. [Dictionary in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and  I suggest you to read this post [Dictonary in .net](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dictionary.Add("cat", 2);
    dictionary.Add("dog", 1);
    dictionary.Add("llama", 0);
    dictionary.Add("iguana", -1);
```

to check. use ContainsKey [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("key"))
    dictionary["key"] = dictionary["key"] + yourValue;
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who has to use a List (which was the case for me, since it does things Dictionary doesn't), you can just use a lambda expression to see if the List contains the Key:

```
list.Any(l => l.Key == checkForKey);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need use the list,you must foreach the list,and look for the keys.
Simplely,you can use hashtable.

Answer (score 4):

Your needs exactly describe the design of [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/xfhwa508.aspx)s?

```
Dictionary<string, string> openWith = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no  
// duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
openWith.Add("txt", "notepad.exe");

// If a key does not exist, setting the indexer for that key 
// adds a new key/value pair.
openWith["doc"] = "winword.exe";
```

Comment: Map is a very Javaish word ;p

Comment: @Olivarsham Check my answer, you want `Dictionary`

Answer (score 4):

For sure, dictionary is preferable in your case. You can not modify the Value of `KeyValue<string,int>` class as it is Immutable.

But even if you still want to use `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();`. You can use `IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`. Code will be like.

```
public class KeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
{

    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, int> x, KeyValuePair<string, int> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, int> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use it in Contains like

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        string checkKey = "my string";
        if (list.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(checkKey, int.MinValue), new KeyComparer()))
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, int> item = list.Find((lItem) => lItem.Key.Equals(checkKey));
            list.Remove(item);
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("checkKey", int.MinValue));// add new value
        }
```

which does not sounds good way.

hope this info helps..